# If two computers use the same VPN can they be targeted with local IP addresses and avoid port forwarding?

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, port-forwarding

If I am using a VPN and my friend is using the same VPN and has some program listening on a specific port on his computer, can I access that computer and port with a local IP address instead of having to use his real ip address and configure port forwarding?

I.E. can I access it just like we are on the same home network?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by using same VPN?  Are you both using VPNs to connect to the internet independently?  Are you both using VPNs to connect to a common network or is one of you connecting to the other's local network via VPN?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on *where* the VPN is "terminating". There are two possibilities.

If the VPN is terminated at the PC, e.g. in Windows, then no you cannot (or rather should not) since traffic to the remote network is forced into the VPN on the computer & you would have to define a "split tunnel" to hive off some traffic to go to other devices on the local network without it going through the VPN. That is insecure and adds significant risk to the remote end of the VPN, not recommended, at least without specific permission from the owner of the VPN.

If the VPN is terminated at the router, your local network is an extension of the remote network and then you **can** talk between local PC's.

It is possible that you have a VPN only to hide some activity from your local service provider or local law enforcement. In that case, creating a split tunnel is probably not really an issue. But to give specifics would require further information about the OS being used and the VPN software and configuration.

Comment: I think I might not have been clear in my (now edited question), you mention ` local PCs` I am asking about connecting to a PC that is not local but is using the same VPN, Can you clarify?

Comment: I would need to know something about the VPN. Public VPN of the type in the last para of my answer are very different in architecture to private ones for protecting organisational networks. If you can give some additional information, I'd be happy to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With a VPN, you extend your private network over untrusted public network (the Internet).

You should then be able to reach other computers with their local IP address, as soon as your client is configured for and if your network topology is compatible : you can be on different subnets for instance.